# Magento2.3.4 advanced Bundling error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, speedoptimization

> Tracing dependencies for: `mage/bootstrap` Error: ENOENT: no such file
>   or directory, open '`C:/wamp64/www/Project`
>   [image]`/pub/static/frontend/Hiddentechies/custom/en_US/mageTranslationDictionary.js`'
>   In module tree:
>       mage/bootstrap
>          Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bootstrap
>            Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap
>             Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/i18n
>                mage/translate
>
> Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '`C:/wamp64/www/Project/pub/static/frontend/Hiddentechies/custom/en_US/mageTranslationDictionary.js`'
>   In module tree:
>
> mage/bootstrap
>
> Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bootstrap
>
> Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap
>
> Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/i18n
>
> mage/translate
>
> ```
> at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
> ```

Getting this error after running the bundling command.

Comment: I found the similar error a couple days, but got it ridden of when I rebuilt build.js leaving me wondering how that fixed this error.